# How to properly set scrollLeft in two objects using defineSetter?

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll

In my page I have two tables of same width, and them both do horizontal scroll. I need to set both tables to the same position when each one scrolls.

Actually, my code is:

```
var scrollA = $('#scrollA'),
    scrollB = $('#scrollB');

scrollA.on('scroll', function() {
    scrollB[0].scrollLeft = scrollA[0].scrollLeft;
});
```

It works. The problem is that there are situations where the loaded data is big enough to slow the browser and the scroll event.

Then, I'm trying to improve the user experience in those situations.

---

I did this snippet where I try to use the `__defineSetter__` function of `Object`:

```js
var elementA = { scrollLeft: 30 },
    elementB = { scrollLeft: 30 };

elementA.__defineSetter__('scrollLeft', val => elementB.scrollLeft = val);

elementA.scrollLeft += 5;
console.log(elementA.scrollLeft + ' == ' + elementB.scrollLeft);
```

But as you can see running the snippet, it sets `undefined` to `elementA.scrollLeft` and `NaN` to `elementB.scrollLeft`.

I'd like some guidance here, thanks for your time.

Comment: `__defineSetter__ is ` is deprecated, use `defineProperty()`

Comment: Instead of having separate scrollbar for each table why can't u try putting both of them in a container and have a scrollbar to that container so that we can avoid this scenario. I m suggesting this bcoz u said both table has same width

Comment: @Varatharaj. Actually, it is a plugin I'm working on which freezes columns and/or headers of a table... I can't test it now, but I will try your idea later

Comment: @Varatharaj. Your idea (wrapping in a container) would work only with fixed columns or fixed headers, but won't if there are both fixed columns and fixed headers. Basically, I need to set scrollTop when `fixedColumn` or `Content` scroll vertical, and scrollLeft when `fixedHeader` or `Content` scroll horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll events can fire at a high rate, so you may get smoother scrolling by throttling the scroll event handler, as trincot said in his answer. You can throttle a function using `setTimeout`. When moving things on the screen or dealing with other visible effects, though, I prefer [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

`requestAnimationFrame` runs the callback before the next repaint, so the browser can do some optimizations.

This code will get you closer to the solution, it is based on [this example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Example):

```
var scrollA = $('#scrollA'),
    scrollB = $('#scrollB'),
    running = false;

scrollA.on('scroll', function() {
  // if we already requested an animation frame, do nothing
  if (!running) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      // synchronize table B and table A
      scrollB[0].scrollLeft = scrollA[0].scrollLeft
      // we're done here and can request a new frame
      running = false;
    });
  }

  running = true;
});
```

You can use the timestamp passed to the callback to further debounce the synchronization, but you may end with a kinda sluggish scroll in the second table if you put too much delay.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `__defineSetter__` *replaces* the property *scrollLeft* with one with the same name, which means you cannot get to the original property any more. Once you have called `__defineSetter__`, any reading of the property results in `undefined`:

```
console.log(scrollA[0].scrollLeft); // some number, like 10
scrollA[0].__defineSetter__('scrollLeft', val => scrollB[0].scrollLeft = val)
console.log(scrollA[0].scrollLeft); // undefined
```

Also, the browser does not change the *scrollLeft* value via an assignment as you would do in JavaScript, so the setter function will not be called during a scroll event. You can verify this by putting a `console.log` in the setter function: nothing is displayed when you scroll:

```
scrollA[0].__defineSetter__('scrollLeft', val => console.log(val))
```

For the above two reasons there is no hope you can capture scrolling changes using `__defineSetter__`. You need to listen to the `scroll` event like you did first.

You might get better results if you do the synchronisation asynchronously, and skip some of the updates when you have many scroll events occurring:

```
var scrollA = $('#scrollA'),
    scrollB = $('#scrollB'),
    tmr = -1;

scrollA.on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(tmr);
    tmr = setTimeout(_ => scrollB[0].scrollLeft = scrollA[0].scrollLeft, 0);
});
```

Now when the browser generates more than one scroll event instantly, the second one will pre-empty your scheduled update of `scrollB[0].scrollLeft`: the `clearTimeout` will prevent that update from happening, and the next one is scheduled instead.

You could play with the delay argument of `setTimeout` to find the right balance:

Increasing the delay will prevent events from stacking up, and so *scrollB* will then synchronise in a more responsive way, but fewer updates will be made to *scrollB's* *scrollLeft* property, which can make it scroll less fluently.

Comment: Unfortunately the `clearTimeout` does not synchronise both scrolls. I think it acts more like an `scroll-end` event.

Comment: The use of `clearTimeout` is not intended for synchronising, but for emptying the time-out queue. It does not end the scrolling, which is driven by the scroll event it is responding to, and gets treated by the `setTimeout`. If you see a problem, could you demonstrate it in a fiddle?

Comment: @Guedes Try using `requestAnimationFrame`, see [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Example) from MDN. I think it's not possible to get perfect synchronization, at least in low-end devices

Comment: @jbmartinez. WOW !! ...dude, this is awesome, I can't say it worked 100%, but almost it !! ... I was having problem with situations like Financial, Sales, Trade and SCM (where the table data is big) ... Now, just Sales (_really_ big data) slows the scroll event (although not so slow as before). If you mind add an answer, it'd be a valuable one !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.  Make it one table.  Keep it simple.  See example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 2000px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Ernst Handel</th>
    <th>Roland Mendel</th>
    <th>Austria</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```