# Mozilla scroll advice

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mozilla, requestanimationframe

I need a sticky bar to be visible and fixed after a certain scroll. I was going to use scroll event, then I met Mozilla page which advise to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` as the following :

```
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  // do something with the scroll position
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });
  }
  ticking = true;
});
```

I have a few questions :

**1** - What is the logic behind ticking ?

**2** - It seems to me that ticking will always be true since if statement doesn't return anything. This will lead to doSomething function will be called only once. I guess I am wrong, what am I missing?

[mozilla link of scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

Comment: I just checked , It works but why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Default browser behavior

On each scroll event (be it 1 pixel or more), the browser will repaint the layout. (for obvious layout purpose)

#### The performance problem

Your function `doSomething()` *may* not finish before two triggered scroll events. You can see it as a *stack of `doSomething` functions* because there  will be more calls than your execution time can handle.

#### requestAnimationFrame()' solution

This function is defined in the `window` object by default. It tells the browser to wait the execution of the passed function before repainting the layout.

#### The idea of ticking

As you can see, `ticking` will only be `false` after `doSomething()`. It avoids the previous mentioned `stack of events`. It avoids executing the code of another scroll event before the function finished and the browser repainted the layout.

#### Conclusion

It adds performance to your scroll. I asked some days ago [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384367/6188402) which illustrates this situation.